# Auto-generate a service, its DTOs, and a DAO

Tags: c#, automation, servicestack

I am using ServiceStack to connect my thick client to our API server, and I like it a lot. However, I find having to write three classes for every request (Foo, FooResponse, and FooService) to be somewhat of an annoyance.

In my project, I have a lot of DAO interfaces, that look something like this:

```
public interface ICustomerDao {
    public IList<Customer> FindCustomers(long regionId, string keyword);
}
```

I would like to be able to say something like this:

```
public interface ICustomerDao {

    [AutoApi("Loads customers for the given region whose names match the keyword")]
    [AutoRoute("/search/customer/{regionId}/{keyword}"]
    public IList<Customer> FindCustomers(long regionId, string keyword);
}

public class SomeBusinessLogic {

    [AutoService(typeof(ICustomerDao))]
    public IList<Customer> FindCustomers(long regionId, string keyword) {
        // lots of business logic here
    }
}
```

And then, I would like the following classes to be auto-generated for me:

- `FindCustomers`: a ServiceStack DTO request
- `FindCustomersResponse`: the response
- `FindCustomersService`: a Service that takes a FindCustomers DTO, then calls `SomeBusinessLogic.FindCustomers(req.RegionId, req.Keyword)` and wraps its return value in a `FindCustomersResponse`
- `ApiServiceCustomerDao` : Implements `ICustomerDao` by auto-generating methods that construct FooRequest and contact the appropriate service, then receive FooResponse and unpack it automatically.

Does something like this already exist ? If not, how hard would it be to implement ? Is there a better way ?

Comment: I've got no idea about service stack, but what you're describing is crying out for generics. If they don't work because the tools you're using can't serialize requests properly (and if you are not ready to abandon them for that limitation) you can probably write a t4 template to generate the classes in question based on some attributes (e.g. what you have suggested above)

Answer (score 2):

### [AutoQuery](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Auto-Query)

I'd first recommend looking at [AutoQuery](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Auto-Query) to see whether it's suitable for quickly creating data-driven Services.

### Dynamically generate and register Services

As ServiceStack promotes a code-first dev model and your Request and Response DTO's represent your Service Contract I'd strongly recommend against attempting dynamically generate them as you should retain full control of its definition, but you could use them as a template to dynamically generate your own Service implementations by following the same approach [AutoQuery uses to generate your Services implementations and register them dynamically](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/c5daceddf502466e8e9fc1a8084495e906e4598e/src/ServiceStack.Server/AutoQueryFeature.cs#L151-L208).

In AutoQuery you'd just need to define your Request DTO and the rest of the Service implementation are dynamically generated and registered. Since it returns a standard `QueryResponse<T>` Response Type no DTO's are dynamically generated and thanks to the code-first Request DTO, clients [still retain an end-to-end Typed API](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Auto-Query#clients-continue-to-benefit-from-a-typed-api), e.g:

```
var movies = client.Get(new FindMovies { Ratings = new[]{"G","PG-13"} });
```

Comment: AutoQuery sounds good, but can I use it to execute custom business logic code, or is it limited to SQL queries and queries on collections ?

Comment: @Bugmaster it's primarily for creating data-driven services but still allows for [custom implmentations](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Auto-Query#custom-autoquery-implementations) as well as [extensibility with query filters and common base class](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Auto-Query#extensibility-with-queryfilters). But if you still require more control, you can look at AutoQuery's approach for creating and registering dynamic services.